# How to set timeout to a spark task or map operation ? (Or skip long running task)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timeout, job-scheduling

I am using spark to parallelize one million tasks . For example, trainning one million individual models.

I need make sure as much success as possible , but alow failures .
In spark, if there is only one model can't found best solution, it may get hanged and keep running forever. In this situation, the spark job would never finish, and kill this job would not save other 999,999 models to hdfs .
This problem is really hurt .

I searched around but nothing useful found :

- `spark.task.maxFailures` : There is no failure, so this doesn't take effect .
- `spark.network.timeout`: There is no network problem.
- `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval`: No relative .

core trainning code, mainly using rdd.map to train

```
df1 = (df.rdd
      .map(lambda r: r.asDict())
      .map(lambda d: transform_data(d))
      .map(lambda d: create_model(d))
      .map(lambda d: model_fit(d))
      .map(lambda d: pickle_model(d))
)
```

How to set timeout to a spark task ? Or is there any good sulotion ?

Comment: Not sure I follow the line of thinking.

Comment: identify which transformation might be long-running and wrap it up that particular transformation record level with thread and retrieve result with timeout. here you can specify timeout interval as your wish..... spark does not provide default support

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be controller at configuration level. It might happen that you want to apply this to only a subset of spark tasks. `SparkListener` can help with that since you can hook at task, stage, job level and then take decisions to cancel a task using the `sparkContenxt`.

```
 /**
   * Called when a task starts
   */
  def onTaskStart(taskStart: SparkListenerTaskStart): Unit
```

On the above you can implement the timeout logic.

Kill a specific task can be done using sparkContext using the `def cancelStage(stageId: Int)`

You can get the specific ids from the listener events